# Negating in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
index =0;
int[]array = new int[10];
while((!salaries==-1) && index<salaries.length){
```

I want to let up to 10 users enter their salaries, and exit the loop using -1. would this work? is my exclamation mark used correctly? ty O_O

Comment: No you should get an error because of the exclamation mark. You should be using `while(salaries != -1)` the `!=` means not equal to.

Comment: what data type is salaries?  If it's a list or array then it can't be compared to an int

Comment: @JohnScattergood That's most likely the problem since he's doing `salaries.length` later.

Comment: I meant to write while(salaries[index]!=-1 && index<salaries.length){

Comment: @Hello if you do that be careful of going out of bounds if index is larger than the size of salaries.  Protect yourself by reversing the order of conditions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you initialize the values in a `salaries`array with 0 and want to exit when the salary is -1 then you want to check the following:

```
while (index < salaries.length && salaries[index] != -1)
```

Comment: I want to use -1 as a sentinel value to let the user leave the while loop. I changed my answer:  while(salaries[index]!=-1 && index<salaries.length){

Comment: I fixed my answer, but I'm not sure how the salaries[index] will get set to -1 or what it's initialized to